# Export source project to WAR using command line

Tags: eclipse, command-line, export, project, war

I want to export a eclipse project in a file .WAR using command line .

In Eclipse I do

> File -> export -> web -> WAR file

I can deployed the WAR file in Glassfish  and that work well. The size of the WAR is 44700 Kb.

In command line I do this `-> "jar uvf XYproject.war XYproject"`
I have the `XYproject.war` with the size of  90200 Kb and when I deploy that in Glassfish. Nothing run.

I don't understand why the size of the WAR is not the same using command line or using eclipse and I don't understand why the WAR don't work ?

Comment: Could you try to use "cvf" options instead of "uvf" and tell us it it changes something.

Comment: @Aurelien , I have the same wrong WAR file and I have the same problem using `jar uvf XYproject.war XYproject` and `jar cvf XYproject.war XYproject`.

Comment: Try to open each war with a zip tool like 7zip for example to see their content. Once you've done that you will be able to determine why they are different. Then you could understand how to adjust the command.

Comment: It is not the same content , with `File -> export -> web -> WAR file ` it is like a WAR to deploy to Glassfish and with `jar cvf XYproject.war XYproject` it is a copy from the content inside workspace/XYproject.
That mean `jar cvf XYproject.war XYproject` doesn't work for what i want to do.